# Teste de criptografia divergindo da execução da classe

Tags: java, criptografia, aes

Fiz minha classe em java para criptografia usando o AES. Porem fui testar ela nesse site aqui: http://aesencryption.net/

> Classe java:
>   **texto**: teste
>   **chave**: abcdefghijklmno1
>   **resultado**: 5brjBUDRtK7OzHLZf/Pv9A==

porem o resultado do site foi diferente: `9rHpDdonevdWy+1PnTSweA==`

```
public String encrypt(String Data, String pKey) throws Exception
  {
    Key key = generateKey(pKey);
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    return new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
  }
```

A duvida e a seguinte qual das 2 criptografias esta correta?

Comment: E olha que legal, se eu pego a classe java que eles disponibilizam esse é o resultado `tLVGNiaoZ1YQA68tNS8C4w==`. Tá tudo doido rsrs.

Comment: Pode disponibilizar o seu método `generateKey()`? E também a String `ALGO`.

Comment: `private Key generateKey(String pKey) throws Exception
  {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(pKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
    return key;
  }`

Comment: private static final String ALGO = "AES";

Comment: Obrigado @GustavoCinque consegui resolver XD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolvi mudando a seguinte linha:

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
```